# How to create youtube auto-subscription link that works for mobile?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to create a youtube auto-subscription link, that works in mobile. I thought it will work out if the link is opened in browser, instead of youtube app.
But I tried that, it is not working. Any ideas?
The idea behind it, is I want to convert my website visitors to youtube subscribers.
My website is a wordpress website. Maybe it can be done by using javascript?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 var canClick = true;
 var count=0;
    $("body").click(function () {
        if (canClick) {
           if(count){
              window.open("https://www.youtube.com/channel/example?sub_confirmation=1").blur();
              window.focus();}
              count=count+1;
              canClick = false;
              setTimeout(() => {
              canClick = true
            }, 8000);
         }
      });
   });
```

I tried to include this js file before body closes in wordpress. It didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are opening a YouTube link on a mobile that has the YouTube app installed it goes directly inside the app. This behaviour is intended and it's client-side. A bit like using `mailto:` will open a link in a mail client.

So I cannot think of a way to force YouTube to use the browser without YouTube providing this. E.g. a link to a special subdomain that does not switch to the app - but as far as I know there is no such link provided by YouTube.

From (I think) iOS10 onwards and on Android the user can actively choose to open the link in a browser window, bu that's nothing you can control via JavaScript or any other web technology.